# Virtualbox Guest Additions problem

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am kind of new to the Linux world and I have tried to install virtualbox guest additions several times in the correct way, but I do not know why the final results become like what [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgRjR.png)you can see in the screenshot I have taken.

After that I can not use the OS in virtualbox. It looks like the ubuntu get corrupted and I can not right click in maps to open terminal in them, and the screen keeps being small in the left top corner.

I have installed the latest version of Ubuntu Desktop and Virtualbox.

My Ubuntu version is : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS , The Host is Windows 10 pro 64 bit, VB version is : 6.1

Here is how I install Guest additions and the log I get in terminal:

1. I run "sudo apt update" in terminal.

Here is the log:
https://pastebin.com/sd71yvyq

2. I run "sudo apt install dkms" in terminal.

The log:
https://pastebin.com/nKQTYQ6F

3. I insert the Guest Additions CD Image, then I open the mounted virtual CD drive, then I open a terminal in it and run this command: ./autorun.sh

The log:
https://pastebin.com/8th8Xx3F

Then I hit the enter and restart the Ubuntu, and those issues I mentioned happen.

I hope you can help me to solve it.

Thanks in advance,
Mn.

Comment: How did you install guest additions?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the host system? What is the VB version?

Comment: My Ubuntu version is : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS , The Host is Windows 10 pro 64 bit, VB version is : 6.1

Answer (score 2):

Install `dkms` first by

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

Then install the Guest Additions again.

The problem is that by default Ubuntu doesn't have required packages to build a kernel module.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, thanks for your reply. I ran these commands in terminal before installing guest additions: "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)". I will try to install dkms now and will tell you the results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So how did you install Guest Additions?

Comment: Hi again. I installed dkms, but it did not help. I get the same issue. It seems after installing guest additions, Ubuntu gets corrupted. I can not right click in maps to open terminal and the screen as shared before does not expand to full screen.

Comment: So how did you install Guest Additions? I am asking this a 3rd time.

Comment: To install guest additions, I run those two commands posted before in terminal, then I insert Guest Additions CD Image, I open the mounted virtual drive, run terminal in it, then I run "./ autorun.sh" in terminal.

Comment: OK. Then do it again and post the output in the terminal to your question. Edit the question for that. And please answer my comments under your question. Add this information to the question too.

Comment: Ok sure, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best to re-start from a fresh install of Ubuntu as I encounter same problem when checking unattended guest additions installation in expert mode.

I ran the following two line to install the build tools

**sudo apt-get -y install build-essential**

**sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**

then install the Guest Additions

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem.

I removed the Guest Additions and went for the Settings panel inside Ubuntu: this defaults to 800x600 resolution, which is completely unusable, but allows you to change it.

If you have a typical fullHD screen you can use 1440x900 that is fully inside the virtual box screen.
Is far from optimal but at least one can work with this setup.

Kind regards.